# What is the sum of the series $\sum\limits _{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Different methods to compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2)

What is $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}$ as an exact value?

Comment: pi^2/6 due to Euler

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Specific_values

Comment: I suggest you to google 'Basel's problem'. Then you will get a numerous resource on it, including diverse proofs.

Comment: Don't miss Robin Chapman's collection of 14 proofs here: http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/etc/zeta2.pdf

Comment: Just because it's Xmas doesn't mean you can resurrect closed questions with pointless edits, Rahul!

Answer (score 1):

This is a very well-known series. Astoundingly enough, the exact value is $\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$.

There are proofs here: http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/etc/zeta2.pdf

A reasonable video presentation here: http://mathnotations.blogspot.com/.../pi-squared-over-6-algebraic-genius-of.html

And a duplication of Euler's original proof here: http://www.cs.nthu.edu.tw/~wkhon/random/tutorial/pi-squared-over-six.pdf

I prefer the last one, as it's closely related to Viete's infinite product for $\pi$.